# Нужен ли мета тег description?

Tags: seo

Подумал что нет, так как google берет автоматически текст со страницы и подставляет его сам. А чтобы на главной, подставлялся, не какой то текст из постов, а именно мой, который бы описывал главную страницу сайта, то я решил сделать description только для главной, и для некоторых статичных страниц, типа контакты, о нас.
Вопрос в том принял ли я верное решение ?

Comment: Ваш вопрос нужно закрыть из-за того, что в нём нет чётких критериев верного ответа -- такие правила на stackoverflow. Большинство вопросов, которые задаются по seo не имеют такого чёткого критерия: поисковые машины неохотно раскрывают детали своей внутренней кухни, из-за чего вся деятельность seo'шников напоминает толи кухню реверс-инженеров, толи шаманские камлания. А вас интересует именно seo-составляющая, а не юзабилити. Так что путь вам на форумы сеошников, их достаточно много, из русских самый известный это searchengines.ru Ну и в ответ писать не буду, но: я этот тег проставляю.

Comment: Спасибо, за наводку, закрывайте вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Согласно [официальному блогу Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/06/better-snippets-for-your-users.html):

> Чем более описательный и релевантный фрагмент результата поиска, тем более вероятно, что люди нажмут и будут довольны страницей, на которой они приземляются. Исторически, эти отрывки собираются из 3-х мест: *содержание страницы*, *мета-описание*, списки DMOZ.

В настоящее время DMOZ закрыт, поэтому вы можете игнорировать этот пункт. Далее в этом блоге сообщается:

> Содержимое страницы является очевидным выбором для фрагментов результатов, а контент, который может быть извлечен, часто является наиболее актуальным для запросов людей. Однако бывают случаи, когда сам контент не является лучшим источником для фрагмента.

Таким образом, игнорируя мета описание, вы сокращаете информационную базу для поисковиков о ваших веб-страницах. Как следствие, игнорируя мета описание, вы способствуете понижению поискового ранга ваших веб-страниц и всего веб-сайта.

Для проверки поисковой выдачи используйте [оператор `info`](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=ru), пример: `info:https://example.ru`.

См. [справку Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=ru&visit_id=1-636375919697406343-1205128108&rd=1#1) об этом.

Answer (score 2):

В [справке Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/recommendations/using-meta-desc.xml) рекомендуется задавать описание веб-страницы и приводятся такие рекомендации.

1. Мета-описания не должны быть короткими, в несколько слов.
2. Должны описывать конкретную страницу сайта, а не сайт в целом.
3. Мета-описания должны быть написаны для людей, нормальным человеческим языком — развернуто, правильно выстроенными предложениями, без злоупотреблений ключевыми словами, фразами, заглавными буквами, рекламными лозунгами и пр.
4. Мета-описания должны быть емкими и при этом содержательными. Старайтесь выразить основную суть документа в нескольких предложениях.
5. Содержимое тега meta должно быть актуальным, отражать текущее состояние страницы.
6. Мета-описания должны соответствовать языку документа.

Кроме того, поисковые машины могут использовать значение этого тега для [формирования заголовка](https://yandex.ru/blog/platon/2803) результата. А в [вот тут, в разделе «Обучение»](https://yandex.ru/adv/edu/webmaster-optimization/kak-formiruetsya-snippet-sayta), констатируется, что *хорошее* описание редко бывает короче 80 символов.

---

Ещё ценность этого тега заключается в автоматическом заполнении поля с описанием, когда пользователь пытается создать закладку на страницу сайта в своём браузере.